# jQuery Mobile JSON formatting

Tags: jquery, json, listview, jquery-mobile, jsonp

I have a listview generated by JSON but I don't know how to dynamically create the div tag to hold all list item elements.  It looks like a list without any CSS formatting.  I don't know what I am doing wrong.  This is the problem page: http://mbeta.calvaryccm.com/#teachings  This is what I want it to look like: http://mbeta.calvaryccm.com/  I don't know how to format my listview to show what I need it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding content dynamically (via ajax), you'll need to initialize or refresh the list view:

```
$('#mylist').listview();
// or if you already have a listview that you are appending to
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

See [Calling the listview plugin](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i can not write the whole code here but i am sure you will need to write something as this:

```
// i assume your JSON response is stored in data object
// following is the loop which reads the data object ,gets the value and append it to the `<li>` of `<ul>`
```

var list= $("").attr("id","list"); //create a new ul element dynamically in jquery

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{

var li=$("<li/>").html(data[i].name); // get the value of name in JSON and put it in newly created li ,(getting value will depend on your json string format)

$("#list").append(li); //append li to ul of id list

}

$(body).append(list); // append the list to anywhere you want, i am appending it to body.
```