# jquery mobile does not render list after jquery template was inserted

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-templates

I am adding

tags using jquery templates to jquery Mobile website. It adds li tags, however it does not style in the standard jqueryMobile style. I can see it visually and by inspecting DOM: jquery mobile adds classes and convert to div and span classes, where in my case I see plane ul and li tags without any jquery mobile classes. I have a version, that it loads first Jquery Mobile, and then injects jquery template and Mobile does not refresh that list and doesnt style it. Is there a way to fix it and display standard jMobile list after jquery template was injected? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Mobile JSON formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714263/jquery-mobile-json-formatting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

> **Updating lists** If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the `refresh()` method on it to update the styles and create any nested
>   lists that are added. For example:
>
> ```
> $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
> ```
>
> Note that the `refresh()` method only affects new nodes appended to a
>   list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already
>   enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if
>   you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list
>   item, these won't be reflected. If you want a list item to be updated,
>   replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh.

Comment: is there a way to refresh the whole page instead of specific elements? what if I have lists, dropdownlists, divs, lots of inputs on the page and I inject it all with jtemplate, but dont want to write 'refresh' for each one?

Comment: $('#pageId').trigger( "create" ); http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html look at Create vs. refresh: An important distinction