# How to render jQuery Mobile in dynamic clientside templates from a Backbone view?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm building a mobile website using [Brunch](http://brunch.io).

For the user interface, I want to use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

I started out adapting the existing home_view (Backbone.View) as such:

```
class exports.HomeView extends Backbone.View
  id: 'home-view'

  render: ->
    console.log "render() homepage"

    $(@el).html require('./templates/home')

    $.mobile.changePage('#homepage', 'slide', false, false)
    console.log $(@el)

    @
```

This doesn't work, and I suspect it's because Backbone 'injects' the html before or after jQuery Mobile is initialized or something?

I can inspect the markup using Firebug and Chrome's Inspect Element, but the div elements are set to display:none; (so again this seems to point to jQuery Mobile not initializing or something like that)

*./templates/home* is a simple 'eco' template with some basic jQuery Mobile markup, and it looks like this: (and gets injected into the body tag)

```
<div data-role="page" id="homepage">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#helppage">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="home">
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've searched around SA and Google for solutions but didn't manage to pull it off. Any tips would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As stated somewhere in a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743931/jquery-mobile-does-not-render-list-after-jquery-template-was-inserted), you can do this after rendering your page:

```
$("#pageId").trigger("create");
```

This will force jQuery Mobile to update your page and fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

In your render function try :

```
render:function(){
var container = this.options.viewContainer;

// your code

container.html($(this.el));
container.trigger('create');
return this;
}
```

This works fine for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

As per Sandor but the way I've approached this is to trigger the `'create'` event during `'pagebeforeshow'` as follows:

```
$('#pageId').bind('pagebeforeshow', function(event) {
   var currentPage = event.currentTarget;
   $(currentPage).trigger('create');
});
```

This will apply all the styling you lost during the re-rendering of your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above, involving the use of `$(currentPage).trigger('create');` fix the problem, but because the fix is applied afterwards (after the view page has been rendered and displayed by `$.mobile.changePage()`) the user gets an unpleasant side-effect: the view flickers due to the change of style applied by jquery mobile.

My solution to the problem was to trigger custom event from the view once the dynamic rendering is complete and bind the `$.mobile.changePage()` to that event. This causes the output to be "buffered" until complete and then styled altogether.

Here's an example:

In the `initialize` function of my view I have code waiting for an event to be fired by the model/collection when fetched and a function to render the dynamic part of the html:

```
window.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

// some other code here

initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "fetchCompleted:CollectionName",  this.renderRows);
},

renderRows: function (eventName) {
    $(this.el).find('div[class="content-primary"]').html(this.template_ul({data: this.collection}));
    this.trigger( 'view:ready' );
},
//...
```

... then in the router I have the following code for the `changePage()`:

```
myViewObject.on( 'view:ready', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage($(next.el), {changeHash:false, transition: transition});
});
```