# Backbone/jQuery mobile duplicate view

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I've got some problems with my Backbone, RequireJS &  jQuery mobile application.
When I use a form view 2 times the form submit event is fired twice.
Each new view is added to the body and the previous view will be removed. For that I use this code in my app.js file:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;

    $(document).on('pagehide', 'div[data-role="page"]', function (event, ui) {
        $(event.currentTarget).remove();
    });
})
```

**Router.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone',
  'views/projects/ProjectsView',
  'views/projects/AddProjectView'
], function($, Backbone, ProjectsView, AddProjectView) {

  return Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
      'addProject': 'addProject',
      'editProject/:projectId': 'editProject', 
      '*actions': 'showProjects' // Default
    },

    addProject: function() {
      new AddProjectView().render();
    },
    editProject: function(projectId) {
      require([
        "views/projects/EditProjectView", 
        "collections/ProjectsCollection", 
        "models/ProjectModel"
      ], function (EditProjectView, ProjectsCollection, ProjectModel) {
        var projectsCollection = new ProjectsCollection();
        projectsCollection.fetch();

        var project = projectsCollection.get(projectId);
        if (project) {
          var view = new EditProjectView({model: project, projectsCollection: projectsCollection});
          view.render();
        }
      });
    },


    showProjects: function() {
      new ProjectsView().navigate();      
    }

  });
});
```

I've uploaded my code to a directory on my website: http://rickdoorakkers.nl/np2
If you go through the following steps, you'll see the problem:

1. Add a project
2. Add a second project with a different name
3. Open a project by clicking on it and change the values and save it
4. As you can see the event of adding a project is launched and there's a project added instead of changed.
5. This same problem also occurs when you try to change 2 projects after each other. The first project is edited then.

Is there somebody who can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rido, your code is really hard to read for me because of the way it's mixing together a few things and not following any of the usual conventions for Backbone.

For your specific problem, I have a feeling the problem is that you binding both the Edit view and the New view to body (el: body), both respond to the event submit, and you are never clearly cleaning up the views, so I *think* that whenever you add a project and then edit it, the add view is still in memory, still bound to the submit event and still answering the call = new project with the new name, instead of editing.

It's 'easy' to fix in a dirty way, by adding a call to stopListening after adding, but the real problem is that you are binding to body, and mixing togethers the Backbone Router and manual hash control + other weird patterns, such as fetching the collection every 5 lines (you could just create one at the start of the App and always use it! here it's localstorage so it doesn't matter but if you ever move to a remote storage, you'll regret it... fetch() reset the collection and do a full reload!). May I suggest you maybe try to rewrite this without caring about jQuery mobile and just try to make it work with Backbone.Router + a single collection + not binding to body but instead, create the views on the fly and append them to body / remove when you are done? You'll see the bugs will be less weird and easier to track.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I just started to rewrite my code and I hope that I'm doing it right this time. Could you please check my new code at: http://rickdoorakkers.nl/np2
But now I've got some strange jQuery Mobile problem and I don't know what's causing it. When you switch multiple times between the list and the add view you will see that the style is gone after the third time switching. And I've read my code multiple times but I thinks it all correct now.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Rido, the code looks better! If you need to redirect, I'd rather use the Backbone.history.navigate("#project", {trigger: true}) to change the page than do a window.location = "#project", but I guess that technically it's exactly the same.

Comment: For the new bug, the HTML rendered is correct but it's missing all the classes! And the reason for that is that jQuery mobile doesn't work automatically with dynamic content. You need to trigger the "create" event on your DOM after modifying the DOM to get jQuery to do stuff. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258146/how-to-render-jquery-mobile-in-dynamic-clientside-templates-from-a-backbone-view).

Comment: Aah great thanks! That solved the main problem with the CSS style.
But now I've got a strange problem on the list page: http://rickdoorakkers.nl/np2
When you add a project and return to the list view, de first item of the list is behind the topbar. When you refresh the page it's ok, but after a redirect inside the app the first item disappears behind the topbar.

Comment: I think that as per the StackOverflow guidelines, this is getting too off-topic (from the initial question, which was about double binding and not cleaning up the views = Backbone doesn't automatically do it for you) .. I'd suggest to close this one? I had a quick look and the Project header is hidding the first item because it's missing a padding-top: 42px, which I assume is added automatically by jQuery-mobile.

Comment: I did a few quick tests and it seems the problem is with your .trigger("create"). You do it on the $el in your views, but I think here you need to the trigger one level higher for it to compute the padding correctly. Try a $("body").trigger("create") and see if that fixes your issue (I tried it in the console on a debug point and it fixed it so I have good hope) and then try to narrow it down somewhat. jQuery Mobile doesn't look very fun, good luck.